# access a file outside of class python

Tags: python, class

there is a file "words.txt" I have to access it.

```
WORDLIST_FILENAME = 'words.txt'

class Message(object):
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.text = text
    '''
    Initializes a Message object

    text (string): the message's text

    a Message object has two attributes:
        self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
        self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
    '''
    # pass #delete this line and replace with your code here

  def get_message_text(self):
    '''
    Used to safely access self.message_text outside of the class
    Returns: self.message_text
    '''
    # pass #delete this line and replace with your code here
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    a = f.read() #Now you have a string that contains the data inside .txt file
    #You can do whatever you like  with this data from now on
```